# how to do substring of HttpResponse in android

Tags: java, android, string

I want to do substring of following HttpResponse.

```
true#696.887#Nirmal Patel
```

This is string and I want only `Nirmal patel` from whole string.

Comment: Refers these link http://www.javatpoint.com/substring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do this,

```
String yourString = yourResponse.substring(yourResponse.lastIndexOf('#') + 1);
```

Comment: may be `yourResponse.substring(yourResponse.indexOf('#') + 1,yourResponse.lastIndexOf('#') );`

Answer (score 0):

```
String substring= httpresponse.substring(httpresponse.lastIndexOf('#')+1,httpresponse.length());
```

Comment: this print #Nirmal pate  i dont want # and last character is missing

Comment: Can you please explain how it would fix the issue?

Comment: @deepakjohn141 I'm aware of the reference, but please follow the guidelines of stackoverflow.. your solution should explain the benefits and how it would fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly use the `lastIndexOf` Method

```
int index = YOUR_RESPONSE.lastIndexOf("#");
```

Than use the `subString` Method

```
YOUR_RESPONSE.subString((index+1),YOUR_RESPONSE.length());
```